# Drag and drop between maximized applications in Windows 11

Tags: mouse, taskbar, windows-11, drag-and-drop

I am using most of my apps in maximized mode. When I need to drag'n'drop something (usually a file), I don't minimize either of them. Instead, I am:

1. Dragging a file from a source application to a taskbar, to destination app's tab
2. Waiting about 1-2 seconds, while still holding the left mouse click, until Windows shifts focus to the destination tab and bring it to top
3. Moving the mouse pointer to a desired (drop accepting) location and releasing it.

Or, to depict this, like that:

(the depicted operation is dragging a file from Total Commander via taskbar and dropping it to Notepad++)

[image]

I found this operation to be impossible to replicate in Windows 11. Since there are no tabs there on the taskbar (an only icons) then I am trying to drag my file to the destination app's icon. But this fails as I see crossed circle ("not available") mouse pointer and the destination app is never brought to the foreground.

What is the correct way of dragging files between two maximized applications in Windows 11, without the need of minimizing either of them?

Answer (score 1):

The only solution that works in Windows 11 seems to be:

1. Left-click an item in *source* and move mouse cursor a little bit to start dragging process. Don't release it.
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> as many times as needed to bring *destination* to front.
3. Release left mouse button to complete the drag-and-drop process.

With proper experience this becomes even easier than the one from Windows 10.

Answer (score -1):

This feature has been reintroduced with the recent [Windows 11 22H2 update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/status-windows-11-22h2). After installing the update, the drag and drop on the taskbar works again.

Here's how Windows is behaving after the update (in this use case two notepads were open/minimized and I dragged an ini-file from file explorer into one of them):

Step 1: When dragging the file to the taskbar on a minimized application, you get the preview windows

[image]

Step 2: Continue to drag the file to the application window you want to drop the file to (in this case it was the left one)

[image]

Step 3: Executing step 2 will "unmaximize" the window and will appear in the position where you minimized it

[image]

Step 4: Continue to drag the file inside the now available notepad window and drop it there. This will open the file inside notepad:

[image]

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: Sorry, can't confirm. I've got _Windows 11 Pro **22H2**_ (22621.963) installed on _28.‎09.‎2022_ and drag'n'drop to taskbar doesn't work at all (yet | still | again).

Comment: @trejder works perfect for me, same Version: 22H2 (22621.963), did you install any modifications like ExplorerPatcher etc.?

Comment: @Albin Nope. For my core system, Microsoft is my lord. I don't install anything that isn't installed by them and I install everything that they told me to install. Maybe they have introduced some configuration switch with this update that I have turned off? I did some very limited changes in _regedit_, but nothing touching this area; just some tweak-up around file handling (enabling some extensions) or power plan (turning off auto-sleep).

Comment: @trejder not sure, I can not replicate your behaviour, and I'm not aware of any switch. Can you replicate this behavior on any other system and if so how?

Comment: @trejder did find the problem yet? maybe you could try to setup a new userprofile, or if this doesn't work temp. install a fresh Windows on a tmp. partition (without deleting your current Windows), and see if the problem persists. As I said all the computers I updated manually to 22H2 (and tested myself) the new features are working as intended. The only problems I had were due to centralized domain issues (domain server startup scripts etc.).

Comment: @Albin Sorry, at this moment of time I am very overloaded with other tasks and don't have time to setup another user or test on another computer. However, I have three PCs with Windows 10 that I plan to upgrade to Windows 11 Pro soon, so in about 3-4 weeks I might be able to tell something more. BTW: What do you mean by "_upgraded manually_"? You don't use Windows Update automation?

Comment: @trejder I never upgraded from Windows 10 to Windows 11 (just installed Windows 11 from scratch), so I'm not sure if this might cause an issue. Other than that, by "manual" update I mean that I logged into Windows and started the update myself, and checked it after it was finished. In all other instances, I triggered the client updates via the central server so it was fully automated (and I didn't do any manual checks).

Comment: @trejder I would appreciate removing the downvote (assuming it was you) until you had a chance to actually review it.

Comment: @trejder any news on the update yet?

Comment: @Albin For the feature that I am asking for in my question -- no change. I still cannot replicate what you've said and still cannot confirm that this feature was truly reintroduced. For the retracting the downvote, I'd love to do so, but I can't. I am being hist by "Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited" error. Maybe, if you could edit your answer and include a screencast showing that it is working (like I did in my question to show that it is not working) then we could fix both solution and the downvote?

Comment: I added some screenshots to my answer, that show how Windows behaves when doing a drag and drop on the taskbar. I tried several other Windows 11 machines, they all allow for drag and drop to the taskbar. The only time it doesn't work was when opening a sandbox. Maybe it's worth opening a new question "Drag'n'Drop on Taskbar doesn't work even after installing the 2H22 update"!?

Comment: You should be able to remove the downvote now.